# Azure | AD Application | Secret Expiration

Tags: azure-cli

I have azure active directory application and this application uses some secret. If I have to describe the secret details using azure cli command, what can be done? I didn't find a method to check the expiry of the client secret for the Azure AD Application.

[image]
We can check the expiry from Azure console but how to check that using az command line options?

I tried to check the Azure cli options but couldn't find any resources which can help me doing that

Answer (score 0):

Added the Client secret for the Azure AD Application.

[image]

Copy the `ApplicationID` from the `Overview` section.

[image]

I have followed the MSDocs [az ad app show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-show) and [az ad app credential list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/credential?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-credential-list) and used the below commands to get the Client Credentials Details.

Copy the `ApplicationID` in place of ID.

***Way 1 :***

```cs
az ad app credential list --id ***
```

[image]

The `EndDateTime` is the Expiry Date of the Secret.

```cs
az ad app show --id *******
```

Check the `PasswordCredentials` section in the result.

[image]

Comment: I get below response after I followed the above method:                                                vjain@vjain-Latitude-7400:~/KUBEDR-4363/casactl/terraform-provision-eks-cluster$ az ad app show --id 00f21a7a-f413-44ec-bb6e-007e5c28f626
Continuous access evaluation resulted in challenge with result: InteractionRequired and code: LocationConditionEvaluationSatisfied

Comment: Where you are running the command ?

Comment: I ran the command in my terminal

Comment: Run the command in the `Azure Portal` => `Cloudshell`.

Comment: Check this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QsoH.png).